# Laravel Homestead Swift Cannot send message without a sender address

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I get this error with stock email settings in Laravel 5.1 Homestead when I try to send a password reset mail.

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 162:Cannot send message without a sender address
```

The address is filled in app/config/mail.php:

```
'from' => array('address' => 'myusername@gmail.com', 'name' => 'hawle'),
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In your `.env` file you will need to set the email address and password of your email account. You also need to set the host and port of the mail server you are using.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME= ***USER NAME***
MAIL_PASSWORD= ***PASSWORD***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Or make sure that everything is complete in your `mail.php` file (see note below).

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/
'from' => ['address' => 'myusername@gmail.com', 'name' => 'hawle'],
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

**Note: It's better to use the `.env` file, as you most likely will have a different configuration in your production environment.**

If everything is completed and it still doesn't work, it might be caching. You can clear the config cache with this:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Also note:

- Port 465 is for Gmail. If it does not work, you can use 25.
- The `mail.php` file is located at `/app/config/mail.php` (as OP said).
- The `.env` file is located at the root of your project.
- Mailtrap.io is a service for testing SMTP. It does not really send emails.

**As Viktorminator mentioned:**
*Take into consideration creating app passwords and not using your usual pass for this needs. Link for creating passwords [myaccount.google.com/apppasswords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)*

Comment: I was trying to use mailtrap.io service with this setup and it didn't work. The problem was I think that you should not change this line 
    'from' => ['address' => 'myusername@gmail.com', 'name' => 'hawle'],

Comment: @GergelyHavlicsek Mailtrap is for testing purpose, If you want to send mails to other people you should use your own email account and change the configuration to the smtp that your provider is using for example google uses smtp.gmail.com. If you are using a real smtp you will also need to use real credentials.

Comment: the key problem was MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null. replace it with MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls.

Comment: Take into consideration creating app passwords and not using your usual pass for this needs.
Link for creating passwords https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Comment: if you want to clear the config cache the command is: 
php artisan config:clear right ?

Answer (score 24):

Make sure you have set the 'from' in app/config/mail.php

```
'from' => ['address' => 'myname@gmail.com', 'name' => 'myname']
```

It will fix the problem.

Comment: And do 'php artisan config:cache' after it.

Comment: @pbwned your comment saved me from pulling out my hair

Answer (score 16):

Maybe someone is using laravel 6
Its problem is "Cannot send message without a sender address" so there is no email address to send the email in `.env` file

Just add sender email address

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=your_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@gmail.com **here**
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I didn't change anything in the mail.php file, its work for me in laravel 6, after that run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: All the above done and wouldn't work until i did, php artisan config:cache

Comment: In laravel 7 I had to add MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS in .env

Answer (score 9):

Managed to fix this by doing the following

Goto **.env** file

**Make sure the value for `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` is set.**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=***USERNAME**
MAIL_PASSWORD=***PASSWORD***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@YOURDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 6):

I just solved this in Laravel 7.9. I'm using mailtrap.io and I believe the issue was a missing `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` variable. This variable is not present in the mailtrap.io sample config OR the .env.example file.

Here are my .env settings:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=[found in mailtrap settings]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[found in mailtrap settings]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=me@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 4):

### LARAVEL 7 *cannot send message without a sender address *

---

go to you `.env` file which is located at the root of your folder

---

Then set your configuration for mail like this if you are also using `smpt.mailtrap.io` as MAIL_HOST.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=******username******
MAIL_PASSWORD=******password******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=john@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

---

now to set your `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD`  [click here to go to mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io)

---

now sign up or login if you already have an account for it.

---

then click Inbox then select demo inbox there you'll find the integration dropdown then select for Laravel and it will provide you with the username and password required to fulfill you `.env` file.

---

then save the information in your `.env` file for you Mail Configuration.

---

Now the most important part is that you run these two command line in your terminal.

---

run `php artisan serve` again

---

run `php artisan config:clear`

---

Then do your process and check out the mailtrap inbox.
for me it worked like this.

Answer (score 3):

error was still occure. after settings and run commands

```
php artisan view:clear;
php artisan config:cache;
php artisan cache:clear;
php artisan route:cache;
```

check the code

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('layouts.mail', [ 'content' => 'testmail'],    function ($m) use ($msg2){
$m->from('abc@gmail.com', 'ABC'); 
// this line was env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') ; cant read from .env
$m->to('xyz@gmail.com', 'XYZ')->subject('TestMailSubject!');
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS in env .file is not null.

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@laravel.com
```

the next step you have to use these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 3):

please check your "MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS" should not be empty.
and then use php artisan config:clear

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the .env file, you can add default values to those env calls on app/config/mail.php, like this:

```
    'from' =>  ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM_EMAIL','do_not_reply@email.com'), 'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME','SpongeBob')],
```

This approach will try to get the data from the .env file, if there's nothing there, it'll default to whatever you set.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the solution here but didn't work until I run this three commands

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 2):

In **Laravel 7** , your .env file should be like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME="your username"
MAIL_PASSWORD="your password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
#MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
#MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Make sure these two lines are **commentout** like this...

```
#MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
#MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**Final step:** run these step of command in your terminal to successfully send notification -

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 2):

You May wanna define your mail configs in .env file this way:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=***USERNAME**
MAIL_PASSWORD=***PASSWORD***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@YOURDOMAIN
```

After making adjustment to your env files make sure to use.

**Use**

> `php artisan config:clear`

instead of

> `php artisan config:cache`

This helped me out, Hopefully, it'll help you out as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forgot also to clear config cache ! it was the problem where I was facing !

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gmail account, settings are different now. Config `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@gmail.com
```

You can also ssl encryption and then following settings:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_PORT=465
```

And after setting everything run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

You may also need to check on option "Less secure app access" on https://myaccount.google.com/security.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are facing this challenge in the deployment phase and getting the same error after trying all the above steps, ensure you do not have the MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS duplicated in the .env file. If you have one commented out, delete that too.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the null value of MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS in .env file.

solutions 1:
change the value of the MAIL_FROM_ADRESS to match your email address(don t forget to rerun your server).
solution 2:
keep the .env file as it was but you need to change mail.php(app/config/mail.php):

### from these:

```
 'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS','mail@test.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
]
```

---

to:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => 'mail@test.com',
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these defaults with your own values

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but I already did all above and nothing changed. Did toggle on/off `php artisan serve`.

What I did to solve this problem is by doing `restart the PC` and it's then running smoothly.

Note:

- I was using Ubuntu OS.
- Sometime my PC sleep while `php artisan serve` still running. And I think this might lead to a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the above and still I wasn't getting the expected result. The error instead changed to:
Expected response code 250 but got code “530”, with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

From here all you need to do is restart the development server by running;
php artisan serve

This worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just fill up mail_from_address in your .env file. Then it will be solved.

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@gmail.com
```

Answer (score -2):

The file: /bootstrap/cache/config.php
The change:

```
'mail' => array(
            'driver' => 'smtp',
            'host' => 'mail.yourserversiteemail.com',
            'port' => '25',
            'from' =>
            array(
                'address' => 'panel@yourserversiteemail.com',
                'name' => 'sd',
            ),
            'encryption' => 'tls',
            'username' => 'yourUsername',
            'password' => 'yourPass',
            'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```