# Cannot send message without a sender address in laravel 5.2 I have set .env and mail.php both

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

In forgot password laravel sends email which gives error like :

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 162:
```

Cannot send message without a sender address

i already have set my mail account details in `.env` and `mail.php` both.

My .env :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=raval_himanshu@live.in
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and my mail.php is

```
<?php

return [   

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),    

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'),    

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),  

'from' => ['raval_himanshu@live.in' => null, 'Himanshu Raval' => null],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('raval_himanshu@live.in'),



'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

i have tried `php artisan config:cache` too but after that it gives same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871806/laravel-homestead-swift-cannot-send-message-without-a-sender-address

Comment: sorry my mistake done !!

Answer (score 11):

i have made mistake in `mail.php`

```
'from' => ['raval_himanshu@live.in' => null, 'Himanshu Raval' => null],
```

that should be

```
'from' => ['address' => 'raval_himanshu@live.in', 'name' => 'Himanshu Raval'],
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Can from and name values be set from .env file? It seems not to be working. 'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM'), 'name' => env('SEND_NAME')],

Comment: `'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'name' => null]` worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

just try this code below, because this work for me
in **.env** file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myAPPpassword_Generatedfromhttps://myaccount.google.com/security#signin
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

in **config/mail.php** i change like this

```
 'from' => ['address' => 'myemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin.com'],//default :'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
```

then run the `php artisan config:cache` to clear configurations cache and cache again with new configurations, i hope can help

Answer (score 1):

Just run `php artisan optimize:clear`, its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you should do it in build function in your Mail which you created example is given below

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('example@gmail.com')->view('welcome');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After .env update, please restart php artisan (CTRL+C then php artisan serve)