# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got stuck on this error I trying to configure SMTP  mail on `laravel`

[image: here is the error]

here is my configuration on `.env`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=fff3c01db52ee0
MAIL_PASSWORD=feaeda91dc9ab6
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

[image: here is my mail.php on config]

I have to try to authenticate the SMTP on env  but I keep getting the same error so for now am stack on that error

Comment: Don't forget to restart the Laravel development server after changing `.env` file.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

your `mail.php` on config you declare host as `smtp.mailgun.org` and port is `587` while on env is different. you need to change your `mail.php` to

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailtrap.io'),
```

```
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
```

if you desire to use mailtrap.Then run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: No need to change `mail.php` file, `php artisan config:cache` did the trick

Comment: `env()` helper makes the job and there is no need to change values in `mail.php`. Just ensure that all email settings in `.env` file are correct.

Answer (score 24):

I believe this has been answered in some sections already, just test with gmail for your "MAIL_HOST" instead and don't forget to clear cache. Setup like below:
Firstly, you need to setup 2 step verification here [google security](https://myaccount.google.com/security). An App Password link will appear and you can get your App Password to insert into below "MAIL_PASSWORD". More info on getting [App Password here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=DomainName
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_GMAIL@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_GMAIL_CREATED_APP_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Clear cache with:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Why does it need this when you set mail_driver to sendmail not "smtp"? And why can't Laravel just send from sendmail on the server like Wordpress and every other system that is running on the server...

Comment: So did you set up smtp with sendmail before setting this, as an extra step?

Comment: Not at all! Those were just preset values ignored mistakenly.

Comment: you said 'An App Password link will appear' where there does that appear???

Comment: I have found where it was. After 2stepped auth you get in back  to where it was suggested and now another option under apears. Apps' passwords. Then you enter in and there they ask you to put app name( env('APP_NAME') ). And you get that key finally. I.e. MAIL_PASSWORD value. But now it sends reset letter to spam folder. Otherwize it works ok on localhost  now.

Answer (score 9):

I see you have all the settings right. You just need to end the local web server and start it again with

```
php artisan serve
```

Everytime you change your `.env` file, you need tor restart the server for the new options to take effect.

Or clear and cache your configuration with

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, and if you have tried all the above solutions (what's more likely to happen) and none work for you, it may happen that Guzzle is not installed.

Laravel ships mailing tools, by which is required the Guzzle framework, but it won't be installed, and AS OF the documentation, will have to install it manually:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#driver-prerequisites

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use default `mailtrip.io` you don't need to modify `mail.php` file.

1. Create account on mailtrip.io
2. Go to Inboxes > My Inbox > SMTP Settings > Integration Laravel
3. Modify `.env` file and replace all `null`s of correct credentials:

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

4. Run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If you are using Gmail there is an instruction for Gmail:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64582540/7082164

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

(NOT cache)

Comment: obviously make sure all details in .env are correct first

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Laravel development server after changing ".env", if you used the "PHP artisan serve" command.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying everything literally, clearing the cache, and changing SMTP details, the only solution that worked for me was reinstalling the swift mailer package (downgraded the version) and it worked like a charm

```
composer require "swiftmailer/swiftmailer:^6.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

We got the same error while using [Laravel's *Tinker*](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#tinker) `php artisan tinker` to [send a test email from the *Artisan* command-line tool](https://atymic.dev/tips/laravel-send-test-email/).  This was after changing [Laravel's configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration) to use a local *Sendmail / Postfix* relay configuration and clearing the config cache, as previously suggested.

If you already have *Tinker* open, **it's necessary to exit and restart Tinker** because it also caches the config variables until it's (re)started.

1. Make sure *Tinker* is closed
2. Clear the config cache
3. Start *Tinker*
4. Send a test email

Answer (score -1):

\config\backup.php on line 123

```
    'mail' => [
        'to' => '',
    ],
```