# laravel 7 Cannot send message without a sender address

Tags: php, laravel, mailtrap

i try to create project in laravel. When i try register i have this error :
Cannot send message without a sender address

But i think i good configur in .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:dO3BVdR/GyA8/4slJWwwTKbbGxE6TqushSnQ/eWzt3o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=a67607ba6a03b1
MAIL_PASSWORD=148f1b63a2c87f
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

where is the error? And how i can resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please share your registration code . thank you

Comment: Check this answer it's maybe help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871806/laravel-homestead-swift-cannot-send-message-without-a-sender-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.env` you need to define `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` :

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Name
```