# Cannot send message without a sender address - Laravel Verification Email

Tags: php, laravel

I want a verification email to be sent to every user who newly signs up and I have implemented the steps in [Laravel Documentation][1].

Below is my `User Class`

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

//class User extends Authenticatable
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    
    protected $guarded = [];

    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    
}
```

web.php route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

But after registration, it sends a welcome email as structured but doesn't send the verification email but instead throws the below error.

```
Swift_TransportException
Cannot send message without a sender address
```

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871806/laravel-homestead-swift-cannot-send-message-without-a-sender-address

Comment: check that you have MAIL_HOST key in .env file

Comment: MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=something@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}" in your env file